# How portable is it to use semi-colons as command separators in sed?

Tags: sed

In sed, it is fairly common to use multiple commands separated by semi-colons:

```
$ sed -e '/re/{s//replace/p; q;}
```

However, the standard (eg http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ ) only allows for
newlines as a separator:

```
$ sed -e '/re/{
    s//replace/p
    q
}
```

Are there many common implementations of sed still in use that do not allow the semi-colon?  IOW, can a sed script intended to be portable use semi-colons?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the POSIX specification of `sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) :

> Command verbs other than **{**, **a**, **b**, **c**, **i**, **r**, **t**, **w**, **:**, and **#** can be followed by a `<semicolon>`, 
>   optional `<blank>` characters, and another command verb. However, when the **s** command verb is used with the *w* flag, following it with another command in this manner produces undefined results.

So most commands, besides those mentioned above, can be separated by a semicolon.

`/[^\{abcirtw:#];[[:space:]]*/` :-)

Answer (score 3):

Tricky one... Only reference I could find about this is in the [sed-faq chapter 6.8.1](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/editor-faq/sed/)

> Most versions of sed permit multiple commands to issued on the
>     command line, separated by a semicolon (;).

The only reference towards `;` not working is for `HHSED`, see [Chapter 7](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq.html)

Comment: Weirdly, the command separator isn't documented in sed's (at least GNU) documentation (and no, a FAQ I consider *extra* material, you shouldn't need it to get the full info).

Answer (score 1):

GNU `sed` seems to allow semi-colons in a few places that MacOS X (BSD) `sed` does not.  I don't have the details at my fingertips, now, but several times I've had to modify answers to get them to work properly on Mac.  The issue may have been brace-enclosed command sequences.

Comment: At a mimimum, BSD sed appears to insist upon a final semicolon before closing curly braces where GNU sed does not.  GNU: `{n;p}` BSD: `{n;p;}`