# Multiple replacements with one sed command

Tags: macos, shell, sed, bsd

I'm wondering how I can do a multiple find/replace using a single `sed` statment in `Mac OSX`.  I'm able to do this in  `Ubuntu` but because of the `BSD` nature of `OSX`, the command must be slightly altered.

So, given a file with the string:

```
"Red Blue Red Blue Black Blue Red Blue Red"
```

I want to run a sed statement that results in the output:

```
"Green Yellow Green Yellow Black Yellow Green Yellow Green"
```

My two sed statements with a qualifying `find`

```
color1="Green"  
color2="Yellow"  
find . -type f -exec sed -i '' s/Red/$color1/g {} \;  
find . -type f -exec sed -i '' s/Blue/$color2/g {} \;
```

I've tried several combinations of semicolons and slashes, and looked at [Apple's Dev man page for sed](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html) but with a lack of examples, I couldn't piece it together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [combining 2 sed commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657647/combining-2-sed-commands)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Apple's man page says *Multiple commands may be specified by using the -e or -f options.*  So I'd say

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i '' -e s/Red/$color1/g -e s/Blue/$color2/g {} \;
```

This certainly works in Linux and other Unices.

Answer (score 28):

It is possible to combine `sed` commands using semicolon `;`:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i '' -e "s/Red/${color1}/g; s/Blue/${color2}/g" {} \;
```

This reduces clutter compared to writing multiple `sed` expressions.

I was wondering how portable this is and found through [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20769695/709646) a link to [the POSIX specification of `sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html).

Answer (score 1):

With my recent version of Mac OS, I didn't have a lot of luck with multiple commands inside a single sed call. Instead, I just resorted to multiple pipes each with its own single sed command. I ended up using something like:

```
cat my-raw-input.txt | sed -r -E -e 's/myFirstRegex([^,]+).*/\1/' | sed -r -E 's/mySecondRegex([^,]+)/,\1/' > my-output.csv
```

As a big fan of sed, it's definitely not an ideal or elegant solution, but it worked.

Comment: At least with macOS 12.5.1 it works as expected, e.g.: `echo abcdef | sed -e 's/a/A/g' -e 's/e/E/g'` returns `AbcdEf`.