# How to use sed to replace a string that contains the slash?

Tags: linux, sed

I have a text file that contain a lot of mess text.

I used grep to get all the text that contains the string prod like this

```
cat textfile | grep "<host>prod*"
```

The result

```
<host>prod-reverse-proxy01</host>
<host>prod-reverse-proxy01</host>
<host>prod-reverse-proxy01</host>
```

Continually, i used sed with the intention to remove all the "host" part

```
cat textfile | grep "<host>prod*" | sed "s/<host>//g"; "s/</host>//g"
```

But only the first "host" was removed.

```
prod-reverse-proxy01</host>
prod-reverse-proxy01</host>
prod-reverse-proxy01</host>
```

How can i remove the other "/host" part?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace strings containing slashes with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16790793/608639), [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32907/56041), [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/407523/608639), [Which characters need to be escaped when using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15783701/608639), etc.

Comment: Thanks man. I tried using the \ before special character but it didn't work.

Comment: This looks wrong: `sed "s/<host>//g"; "s/</host>//g"`. Pipe to another invocation of sed. Also see [Multiple replacements with one sed command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19590980/608639), [Join multiple sed commands in one script for processing CSV file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229234/56041), etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use different delimiters for sed substitute command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/how-to-use-different-delimiters-for-sed-substitute-command)

Comment: you could use single command... `sed -E '/<host>prod/ s|</?host>||g' ip.txt` or `sed -nE '/<host>prod/ s|</?host>||gp' ip.txt` depending on what you need... also, don't use double quotes unless you need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -n -e "s/^<host>\(.*\)<\/host>/\1/p" textfile
```

sed can process your file directly. No need to grep or cat.

-n is there to suppress any lines that do not match. Last 'p' in the script will print all matching files.

Script dissection:

```
s/.../.../...
```

is the search/replace form. The bit between the first and the second '/' is what you search for. The bit between the second and third is what you replace it with. The last part is any commands you want to apply to the replacement.

**Search**:

```
^<host>\(.*\)<\/host>
```

finds all lines beginning with `<host>` followed by any text `(.*)` followed by `</host>`. Any text between `<host>` and `</host>` is stored into internal variable '1' using '(' and ')'. Note that (, ) and / (in `</host>`) have to be escaped.

**Replace**:

```
\1
```

Replace found text with contents of variable 1 (1 has to be escaped, otherwise, everything is replaced by character '1'.

**Commands**:

```
p
```

Print resulting line (after replacement).

**Note**: Your search involves removing two similar but not identical strings (`<host>` and `</host>`).

Comment: Using '/' to delimit various parts of find/replace string is not mandatory. You can use any other character. E.g.

`sed -n -e "s-^<host>\(.*\)</host>-\1-p"  textfile`
In this case you do not need to escape the '/'  inside `</host>`

Answer (score 0):

I think this sed is enough

```
sed 's/<[/]*host>//g' infile
```